# Getting `Cannot read property 'vB' of undefined` error with Google Chart API

Tags: google-visualization

This error occurs on this line:

```
  chart.draw(data, google.charts.Line.convertOptions(options));
```

the error is:

> Cannot read property 'vB' of undefined

the error is beautifully rendered by Google's Chart API like so:

[image]

the error appears to be internal to the Google Chart library. My code is as follows, it's working for one server I am using, but not for another server and I cannot figure out why this error is happening!

```
<html>
<head>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">

    debugger;

    google.charts.load('current', {'packages': ['line']});
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    {
      var to;
      window.addEventListener('resize', function (event) {
        clearTimeout(to);  // throttle this call
        if( window.memvizIsReady){
          to = setTimeout(drawChart, 500);
        }
      });
    }

    function drawChart() {

      window.memvizIsReady = true;

      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      data.addColumn('number', 'Time unit');
      data.addColumn('number', 'RSS');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Heap Total');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Heap Used');

      data.addRows(JSON.parse('{{{aa}}}'));

      var options = {

        hAxis: {title: "Entry every {{{ms}}} milliseconds."},
        vAxis: {title: "Memory in Megabytes", format: 'decimal'},

        chart: {
          title: 'Node.js memory usage (RSS, Heap Used, Heap Total)',
          subtitle: '(In megabytes.)'
        },

        width: window.innerWidth - (window.innerWidth)/20,
        height: window.innerHeight - (window.innerHeight)/20,

        axes: {
          x: {
            0: {side: 'top'}
          }
        }
      };

      var chart = new google.charts.Line(document.getElementById('line_top_x'));
      chart.draw(data, google.charts.Line.convertOptions(options));
    }


  </script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="line_top_x"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

does anyone know what this error might be about? using the boolean `memvizIsReady` should prevent calling `drawChart()` before things are ready.

I was able to debug, and get the raw data going into this call:

[image]

the data looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

ughhh, f*cking Google..this happens when no data is collected yet.

```
 data.addRows([]);
```

is what is happening, and apparently Google simple fails if there is no data. That's not good, am going to report them to developer jail.

Comment: here is the issue I filed: https://github.com/GoogleWebComponents/google-chart/issues/210